# Help with a definite integral with a parameter $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(xy)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(xy)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

I am not sure where to even start, I would greatly appreciate a hint.
My initial notion was to somehow add another $dy$ integral and change the order of integration, but the $xy$ stopped me from doing that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I(y)$ be given by

$$I(y)=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(xy)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\tag1$$

Then, differentiating under the integral in $(1)$ reveals

$$I'(y)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+(xy)^2)}\,dx\tag2$$

We can evaluate the integral in $(2)$ by first enforcing the substitution $x\to \sin(x)$ and subsequently using the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution). The result is

$$I'(y)=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+y^2}} \tag 3$$

Finally, integrating $(3)$ from $0$ to $y$, and using $I(0)=0$, we find

$$I(y)=\int_0^y\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\,dy'=\frac\pi2 \text{arcsinh}(y)$$

Comment: oh, that is a cute result ...(+1)

Comment: @tired Feynman comes to the rescue.